# Loops - Adding Numbers - Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

So the program has to add all the numbers from "x" to "y".

But it also has to display all the numbers added :

i.e. 10 to 20 should display 10 + 11 + 12 + 13 + 14 + 15 + 16 + 17 + 18 + 19 + 20 = 165

Here's what I have:

```
Dim firstnum As Integer = Val(TextBox1.Text)
    Dim secondnum As Integer = Val(TextBox2.Text)
    Dim sum As Integer = 0


    While firstnum <= secondnum

        sum = sum + firstnum
        firstnum = firstnum + 1

        Label3.Text = firstnum & "+"

    End While


    suum.Text = "  =  " & Val(sum)
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question or explain the problem.

Comment: You've posted a lot of questions that seem to be tasks set to you or homework assignments, if this is the case then getting answers through SO will probably not teach you what the tasks are designed to teach you.

Comment: Thanks for the concern, however when I ask I learn from the answer and it's usually close to what I was thinking... Computer programming is what I like to do so I'm not asking to get by, just to learn as I'm new to VB (and only its because the only course at my school) .... I already have experience with Java, HTML, CSS. Rest assured that I'm learning a lot. @bendatclear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the following:

```
Label3.Text = firstnum & "+"
```

You are *overwriting* the value in `Label3` every time you go through the loop. What you probably want to do is *concatenate* the existing value with the next number.

This should get you on your way:

```
Label3.Text = Label3.Text & firstnum & " + "
```

Answer (score 3):

Is Linq ok? Then you can use `Enumerable.Range` and `Enumerable.Sum`:

```
Dim startNum = Int32.Parse(TextBox1.Text)
Dim endNum = Int32.Parse(TextBox2.Text)
Dim numbers = Enumerable.Range(startNum, endNum - startNum + 1) 'inclusive, therefore + 1
Label3.Text = String.Join(" + ", numbers)
suum.Text = numbers.Sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

your Label3.Text will only contain the last num and "+" at the end of the algorithm. You should replace

```
Label3.Text = firstnum & "+"
```

with

```
Label3.Text = Label3.Text & firstnum & "+ "
```